# AngularJS $scope doesn't render after being updated

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that listens on `$scope.$on`, which will show a popup window when triggered. It works 100% of the time from a couple other controllers' `$rootScope.$broadcast` methods. But one of them won't work ever.

The controller gets the event, and sets the `$scope` variable needed, but the page doesn't update, even if I fire `$scope.$eval()`. Then, if I go to another route, the `$scope` will finally render, and the modal will pop up on top of that route. I can't tell if I've found a bug in angularjs, or I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: Could you try too distill your problem to a simple scenario and post some code here? It doesn't need to be your project code, just a minimal reproduce scenario.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are probably changing the `$scope` outside of the angular `$digest()`. Try replacing `code making changes` with `$scope.$apply(function(){ code making changes })`. With this the dirty-check should run and update all.

Answer (score 14):

I would recommend using:

`$scope.$evalAsync(function() { // scope changes here });`

This way you won't run into problems like trying to call apply when there's a digest already in progress.